# same article with different categories

Tags: joomla-3.x

Can we access same articles in different categories? I want to show one article in different categories using Category blog layout. Please advise how.

Comment: Please look at this question- http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8858/how-to-categorize-an-article-under-many-categorizes

Answer (score 1):

Joomla does not allow an article to be placed in multiple categories.

But still we can alter the category blog layout to display the desired content.

This can be achieved using [template overriding](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

You need to override category blog layout template and place your code which will check whether the current category is the same in which you want to display that article then fetch the article data and render its content.

This is some sort of a patch you can say, so in case you need to achieve this scenario for large set of articles and categories then you need to write a little generalized code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy the article and save it to the desired category: Edit article, than save as copy, choose different category...save.

And there is another, different option. You can label the requestet article as "main" and display only main articles of the same or different categorys under one menu-item or something like that, module and so on...

Comment: Nooo! What a content maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Yes it is. And imagine you have a multilanguage Website. It´s a mess...but the filter option at the backend is most helpull.